How I can update user information displayed in the UI when data user data stored in shared preferences is updated using riverpod in flutter
I'm still kind of a newbie in flutter. I want to use riverpod state management to update UI showing username and email of user immediately after user updates his or her information. The information displayed is retrieved from shared preferences which is automatically updated once the user updates his or her information
code for retrieving data from shared preference
Future<void> _loadDataFromSharedPreferences() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      token = prefs.getString('token');
      String? userJson = prefs.getString('user');
      if (userJson != null) {
        user = json.decode(userJson);
      }
      firstNameController.text = user!['firstName'];
      lastNameController.text = user!['lastName'];
      userId = user!['_id'];
    });
  }

updating user data in shared preference
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
        print('User updated successfully: ${responseBody['user']}');

        // Update SharedPreferences with the new user data
        try {
          SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          await prefs.setString('user', jsonEncode(responseBody['user']));
        } catch (e) {
          print('Failed to save user data in SharedPreferences: $e');
          showCustomFlushbar(context, "Failed to save user data locally!");
          throw Exception('Failed to save user data in SharedPreferences');
        }

        // Pop the current context
        if (context.mounted) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      } else {
        showCustomFlushbar(context, "Imeshindikana kubadili jina!");
        _btnController.error();
        throw Exception('Failed to update user: ${response.statusCode}');
      } 
  

displaying user information on the ui
 Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
           children: [
             if (user != null) ...[
                  Text(
                                  '${user!['firstName'] ?? ''} ${user!['lastName'] ?? ''}',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 22,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  user!['email'] ??
                                      "+${user!['phone']?.toString()}" ??
                                      '',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ]
                            ],
                          ),

I have read and watched tutorials on riverpod but haven't understood how to implement this. Please help

this is the way I am doing it
first, its recommended to use a class for your user data.
if you don't want to write all the fromJson toJson boilerplate, you can use freezed or dart_mappable to generate it for you
class UserData {
  const UserData({
    required String id,
    this.firstName = '',
    this.lastName = '',
    this.email = '',
    this.phoneCountryCode = '',
    this.phoneNumber = '',
  }) : _id = id;

  factory UserData.fromJson(String json) {
    final data = jsonDecode(json);
    return UserData(
      id: data['_id'],
      firstName: data['firstName'],
      lastName: data['lastName'],
      email: data['email'],
      phoneCountryCode: data['phoneCountryCode'],
      phoneNumber: data['phoneNumber'],
    );
  }

  final String _id;
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String email;
  final String phoneCountryCode;
  final String phoneNumber;

  String get fullName => '$firstName $lastName';
  String get completePhoneNumber => '+${phoneCountryCode.replaceAll('-', '')}$phoneNumber';

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      '_id': _id,
      'firstName': firstName,
      'lastName': lastName,
      'email': email,
      'phoneCountryCode': phoneCountryCode,
      'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
    };
  }
  String toJson() => jsonEncode(toMap());

  UserData copyWith({
    String? firstName,
    String? lastName,
    String? email,
    String? phoneCountryCode,
    String? phoneNumber,
  }) => UserData(
    id: _id,
    firstName: firstName ?? this.firstName,
    lastName: lastName ?? this.lastName,
    email: email ?? this.email,
    phoneCountryCode: phoneCountryCode ?? this.phoneCountryCode,
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber ?? this.phoneNumber,
  );

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) => other is UserData &&
      _id == other._id &&
      fullName == other.fullName &&
      email == other.email &&
      completePhoneNumber == other.completePhoneNumber;

  @override
  int get hashCode => Object.hash(_id, fullName, email, completePhoneNumber);
}

then, since there is no way to subscribe to SharedPreferences, you need to update your ui in the same time that you change the preferences.
The simplest way I found to do it is to update the notifier and to listen for the changes using listenSelf and whenever you change the notifier, the preferences are updated.
class User extends Notifier<UserData?> {

  static const prefKey = 'user_data';
  @override
  UserData? build() {
    ref.listenSelf((previous, next) {
      prefs.setString(prefKey, next.toJson());
    });
    final json = prefs.getString(prefKey);
    if (json == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return UserData.fromJson(json);
  }

  // put here the functions that update the user
}

